# Possessive + non-ing noun phrase (Your joining the forum)

Tags: possessives, noun-phrases

From a grammar book, I got this example of gerund transformation:

> Adam joined the forum.

Transformed into a gerund phrase:

> Adam's joining the forum

What if there is a noun before **joining** like these?

> I'm happy about Adam's **time** joining the forum.
>
> Thank you for your **time** joining the forum.

Are the last 2 sentences correct?

Comment: They're not correct *in this specific case*, because "to join" is considered an  instantaneous event; you would say "He joined the forum in May 2015" but not "He was joining the forum for five months."  You could use it for an ongoing action, like "His time leading the organization" or "His time swimming the ocean", though.

Comment: @stangdon, did you mean _Thank you for your time leading the organization._, _I'm happy about Adam's time swimming the ocean._, or _I'm happy about Adam's time leading the organization._ is fine?

Comment: @stangdon, about the 2 sentences that I posted, when you said they were not correct, did you mean that they are grammatically correct but semantically wrong?

Comment: Yes, I meant that the sentences I posted are fine.  The ones you posted are grammatically correct but semantically wrong, because it sounds like Adam spent time joining the forum, which is not (I think) what you mean; you mean Adam spent time as a member of the forum.

Comment: @stangdon, what I actually meant by _time_ is that for example you are not busy or managed to find time like _Thank you stangdon for your time posting your comments here._. In this case, may I know if _time_ to refer to your free time is awkward?

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457) "From a grammar book" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

They are not correct.

Adam's joining the forum or Adam joining the forum reduces the clause to a phrase. Whatever noun or possessive noun comes before 'joining' is effectively the subject. Time is an odd choice of subject.

I.e. Time joins the forum.

Putting John's before this gerund phrase makes it doubly strange.

Perhaps it's not syntactically incorrect, but it would confuse any native speaker.

Comment: Thank you @Robert. What I actually meant was about having a noun phrase that starts with _time_ as part of a sentence like the 2 sentences that I posted.  By _time_, I'm referring to something like a _free time_, or being able to find time.